# Setting UserTokenProvider throws error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to generate a password reset token using the following:

```
Dim resetToken As String
Dim options As New IdentityFactoryOptions(Of UserManager)

manager.UserTokenProvider = New DataProtectorTokenProvider(Of ApplicationUser)(options.DataProtectionProvider.Create("PasswordReset"))

resetToken = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id)
```

I receive an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on the highlighted piece of code. I simply cannot figure out why as the examples I've researched are identical.

Comment: I know I have old eyes but which line of code is "highlighted"?

Comment: You know, the "highlighted piece"... Also this has been answered many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Well, start a debugger and find out which of the objects are null and see why they are null.